# VB.Net controls not saving set values

Tags: .net, vb.net

I can't seem to figure out how to get my client app's UI to update on network changes.  The basic architecture for the client revolves around NetworkStream async operations.  I have a class that handles all of the various network conditions and sets global variables appropriately.  When a change occurs, I use SendMessage to the main window that needs updating with a custom message.  I verify that this message is being received and follow the execution down to the UIChange() function.  When it gets to the place where an image visibility or label text should change, the line executes fine (no errors or exceptions are thrown) but the value does not stick (i.e. False stays False even though it should be True) and consequently the UI is not updated.  It shouldn't be a cross threading issue because the update function is called from the main windows message WndProc.  I can add the exact same SendMessage code to a button and when clicked will update the UI properly.  So I'm at a loss and would really appreciate any direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have option strict and option explicit turned on in the project settings (they should be on)? In other languages I've experienced bugs like the string "false" accidentally not being parsed into a bool, and it being silently considered as true (because not null) when assigned to a boolean field.

Comment: This is a standard VB.NET problem, induced by using something like Form1.PictureBox1.Visible = true or SendMessage(Form1.Handle, ...) from a worker thread.  Which creates a *new* instance of Form1, one that is not visible.  You will have to use a real reference, not the type name, to the form object that's owned by the UI thread and that the user is looking at.

Comment: You seem to be absolutely right Hans.  If I monitor Sub New() I see that it is being called every time SendMessage is called.  Can you just explain what a "real reference" would be to the form?  Thanks.

Comment: Never mind Hans.  I found a few of your old posts that describe the solution.  Thanks a lot for your help.